# MaterialUI dynamically create checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm getting started on React and MaterialUI by trying to build a simple group of checkboxes. How would I go about trying to dynamically add checkboxes to a component?

I'm thinking that if I pass in a prop like `numCheckboxes=3`, into `CheckboxesGroup`, I should define a function that will add 3 `<Checkbox />` into the document.

Am I on the right track by utilizing `componentDidMount()` to call on a function like `addCheckbox()` 3 times where `addCheckbox()` is something like

```
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.appendChild(<Checkbox />);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wan't to let react have total control over the DOM, so adding it via `document.createElement` goes against that.  So you will need react to actually create and add those checkboxes to the DOM, which honestly is the whole point of the framework because it makes it WAY easier on you.

I put this sandbox together to show you what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/nwx306o2rj

I would also highly suggest looking at the docs, they are really good and will help you learn https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great resource :-)